# MySQL concurrency and auto_incrementing key

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency

I have a MySQL table of Users, and a table of Actions performed by the Users (linked to that User by a the primary key, *userid* ).  The Actions table has an incrementing key *indx*.  Whenever I add a new row to that table, I then update the *latest* column of the relevant Users row with the *indx* of the row I just added to the Actions table.   So something like:

```
INSERT INTO actions(indx,actionname,userid) VALUES(default, "myaction", 1);
UPDATE users SET latest=LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE userid=1;
```

The idea being that I can check for updates for a User by seeing if the *latest* is higher then the last time I checked.

My issue is that if more than one connection is opened on the database and they try and add an Action for the same User at the same time, connection2 could conceivably run their INSERT and UPDATE between the INSERT and update of connection1, and the *latest* entry of the user they're both trying to update will no longer have the *indx* of the most recent action entry.

I've been reading up on transaction, isolation levels, etc.  But haven't really found a way around this (though my understanding of how these work exactly is pretty shaky, so maybe I just misunderstood).  I think I need a way to lock the Actions table until the User table is updated.  This application only gets used by a few hundred users tops, so I don't think the performance hit due to momentarily locking the table will be too bad.

So is that something that can be done in MySQL?  Is there a better solution?  I imagine this general pattern must be pretty common: having one table with a bunch of varieties of rows, and a second table with a row that tracks meta data for each variety in table A and needs to be updated atomically each time that first table is changed.  So I'm hoping there's a solution that  isn't too complex

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) to lock the row in order to serialize the access to the table and prevent from race conditions:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT any_column FROM users WHERE userid=1 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO actions(indx,actionname,userid) VALUES(default, "myaction", 1);
UPDATE users SET latest=LATEST_INSERT_ID() WHERE userid=1;
COMMIT;
```

However **this will slown down your INSERTing rate**, because all these transactions from all sessions will be serialized.

---

The better option i**s to not store the last ID in `users` table at all**. Just use `SELECT max( id ) FROM actions WHERE userid = xxxx` in all places where this number is required. With an index on `actions( userid )` this query will be very fast (assuming that `id` column is the primary key in this table), and the inserts will not be slowed down

Comment: Thanks,  So if I'm understanding this correctly, SELECT...FOR UPDATE basically blocks any other transactions from SELECTING the Users table row with userid=1 until the first transaction COMMITS.  And since the SELECT...FOR UPDATE is the first statement in the transaction, it will effectively ensure that only one of these can run through at a time.  Is that right?

Comment: Also, I considered your other solution, but since my code polls for updates fairly frequently (every few seconds) but only actually does an update every few minutes, I thought it would be faster to have the former case just need to find the one entry in the (small) Users table instead of having to search the entirety of the Actions table each time, even if I then had to do a lock for the (much less common) case of putting a new action in the actions table.  But I've only been at this DB stuff for a few weeks, so I don't have a ton of intuition for performance issues.  Perhaps I'll try both.

Comment: I am aware of a LAST_INSERT_ID() function but is there a LATEST_INSERT_ID() function as well in MySQL?

Comment: Nope, just a typo on my part.  Fixed now.

Comment: Upon reading further, I don't think my understanding is correct.  SELECT..FOR UPDATE doesn't necessarily block other transactions from selecting the relevant rows, only from updating them.  So it wouldn't block another transaction from entering the block because its first statement was blocked becasue it was a SELECT on those same rows.  But maybe it blocks other transactions for doing another SELECT..FOR UPDATE on those rows?  It seems like that would have to be the case, since otherwise two transactions could easily block eachother forever.